# An AppBar application in Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows-10, appbar

I have an application that functions as an "Application Desktop Toolbar", or appbar for short on Windows 10. Everything works fine in Windows 7, but in Windows 10 changed behavior following way:

1. I create appbar - ABM_NEW message, all is correct - appbar height is equal to height needed for one icon and little bit more.
2. Application is closed correct way - appbar hides, appbar is deregistered (ABM_REMOVE) all Ok.
3. If application is closed using task manager (SIGKILL), or it crashes, space occupied by it is not returned to desktop - so in case when I restart app, appbar appears one step lower. On Windows 7 was everything done automatically, space was returned to desktop correctly, but on Windows 10 appeared this behavior.

Is this a bug or is there some way how to ensure that space is returned to desktop correct way (without e.g. some "watchdog", what will periodically check existence of my appbar application (PID) and if disappeared then call proper ABM_REMOVE?)